# Improving JSX Editing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, reactjs, jsx

Is there a way to improve JSX editing in Visual Studio 2017?

Here are my primary issues:

1. VS 2017 does NOT automatically close HTML tags I open in JSX files. For example, I open a new `<div>` and VS 2017 does nothing. I'd like it to auto-close it for me.
2. As you create more and more HTML elements inside the JSX, it gets confusing which tag is closing what -- especially the case with `<div>` tags. Just like with curly braces, it would be nice to click a tag and see its opening/closing tag. When I click a `<div>` in my JSX file, VS 2017 highlights ALL the other DIV's. This is not much use. I'd rather see the corresponding open/close tag -- see below:[image]

Any suggestions on how I can improve my JSX editing experience?

P.S. Please do NOT suggest that I switch to VS Code or some other editor. I'm a full stack developer and I go back and forth between back-end and front-end as I write my code or debug it. Switching between editors would make no sense for me. I do like the power VS 2017 gives me and I just need to improve the experience a bit.

Also, I've already installed Web Essentials 2017 which didn't really address these issues.

Comment: I' curious how did you manage vs2017 to even understand jsx. My installation of vs2017 doesn't even understand the html tags in a jsx file. All my file is a very very very long red underline

Comment: My VS2017 definitely understands JSX. It also offers JSX as an option under Add -> New Item. I think it has to do with the components you install. In my case, i chose both web development and .NET Core. Not sure if this is what did the trick but it's worth a try if you haven't already installed them.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code, i use to add an external plugin auto-close-tag. VS2017 says that it supports unofficial plugins, So my understanding is that it will be supporting this too. As I don't have 2017,I can't test it.